Which limitation stopped Cathleen Bate to create a rule with New Order called "stockpile power" and become like One For All?
Supposedly with New Order  Cathleen Bate can create rules which applies to others but also to herself by calling their names. So Which limitation stopped Cathleen Bate to create a rule with New Order called "stockpile power" and become like One For All?
